# .NET 5, WinUI 3, and WinRT APIs available to Desktop Apps

Tags: windows-runtime, .net-5, winui, winui-3

I have two related questions.

(1) Around 4/2019, Microsoft provided [a list of APIs that can be called from packaged Desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api). (These are in addition to the API that have the DualApiPartition attribute). Has this changed with the November release, is there a more recent version? Is this list going to expand in the future?

(2) When I build a WinUI 3 + .NET 5 packaged desktop application, the libraries linked in under the predefined project include many Windows APIs that are not in the list. Some of these, such as Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingOperation, are clearly UWP API. Others, such as Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintTaskRequest, seem more general purpose. What is the status of all the API that are available in this project definition, can I call them freely from my packaged WinUI 3 + .NET 5 app? Will these be supported going forward, for example are they going to be supported when WinUI 3 supports UWP (in a year or two)?

Comment: Since WinUI3 is still in preview, you'd better ask to the guys building it: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues

Comment: Indeed. That occurred to me while writing the question, but I still somehow clicked the button here :-) I have now re-posted it as [#4065](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4065).